# Intercept a link request in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that parse the web and change the urls to my site to make anonymous surfing.
So for example from a source site www.externalsite.com I replace attribute like

`href="images/logo.png"`

with

```
href="http://www.myanonymsite.com/getpage=www.externalsite.com/images/logo.png"
```

Everything goes well with href, src, etc... attributes or any other full path url.
What is hard is to intercept the url that are construct by cryptic customs javascript functions like:

```
var u = "images";
var i = document.createElement("img");
var ir = Xd(i, u, "logo.png");
Xd = function(i, u , a) {
    i.src = "/" + u + "/" + a;
    return i;
};
```

It is not possible to convert that url before it is built, but is there a way to intercept this request event to modify the url before it is sent to the browser?

Comment: @gurvinder372 Yes I can

Comment: what you want actually? encrypting the url?

Comment: Can I get a warning from your site so that I can go elsewhere avoiding this behavior please.

Comment: @Mark Schultheiss  All src links are converted to something like "http://www.myanonymsite.com/?getpage=www.externalsite.com%2Fimages%2Flogo.png" 
Since I could not figure out that the cryptic script builted an image element, I get a 
404 not found error since it produces a relative url "/images/logo.png".

Answer (score 3):

you can also intercept the link click after they are rendered by overriding their default behavior.

Use this method when you want to alter the link on click

```
function alterLinks()
{
   $( document ).on( "click", "a", function(e){

      e.preventDefault();

      var href = $( this ).attr( "href" );
      //put the logic to update the href

      //finally relocate to that URL as you would have intended to

      location.href = href;

   } );

}
```

Comment: That would be fine if that url was a clickable href, but the problem is that it's a "src" attribute as for images, scripts or styleshets, so it is loaded automaticly by the browser, without any event I know.

Comment: @user284164 Why are not creating the URLs correctly rather than modifying them later?

Comment: Because I can't figure out it is a src url untill it is created by the cryptic function. Say we have an image without attr "src" and that script will create a src url to that image in a non conventional way as in the Xd pseudo-script function.